# How does Kneser Ney estimate ngrams with BOS without dividing by zero?

Tags: natural-language, smoothing, language-models

The recursive formula for (unmodified) Kneser Ney smoothing is [(per Jurafsky08 3.40)](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/3.pdf)

$P_{KN}(w_i | h) = \frac{\text{max}(c_{KN}(h\ w_i) - d, 0)}{\sum_v c_{KN}(h \ v )} + \lambda(h)  P_{KN}(w_i | h)$

where $h := w_{i-n+1}^{i-1}$
and
$$c_{KN}(\cdot) = \begin{cases}
     \text{count(•)}             & \text{for the highest order}\\ 
     \text{continuationcount(•)} & \text{for lower orders}
\end{cases}$$

unfortunately continuationcount is not defined via a formula, but I assume it is the count of all distinct n-grams that can be formed by prepending any word from the vocabulary: $|\{v: C(vw) > 0 \} |$.

Now if i want to calculate the probability for e.g. the bigram `<s> a` I have a problem, because $P_{KN}( \text{"a"} | \text{<s>}) = \frac{\text{max}(c_{KN}(\text{"<s> a"}) - d, 0)}{\sum_v c_{KN}(\text{<s>} \ v )} + \dots$ and $c_{KN}(\text{<s>} \ v' ) = \text{continuationcount}(\text{<s>} \ v') = |\{v: C(v\ \text{<s>} \ v') > 0 \} |$
but no word comes before `<s>` so the sum in the denominator will be zero, thus a division by zero occurs.

This is not an edge case but bound to happen during training, so Im wondering is there any documented solution to this?